# J : creating a family of verbs from an array

Tags: j

The following expression shows a truth table for each of the 16 primitive Boolean operations:

```
   (0 b./; 1 b./; 2 b./; 3 b./; 4 b./; 5 b./; 6 b./; 7 b./; 8 b./; 9 b./; 10 b./; 11 b./; 12 b./; 13 b./; 14 b./; 15 b./) ~ i.2
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│0 0│0 0│0 0│0 0│0 1│0 1│0 1│0 1│1 0│1 0│1 0│1 0│1 1│1 1│1 1│1 1│
│0 0│0 1│1 0│1 1│0 0│0 1│1 0│1 1│0 0│0 1│1 0│1 1│0 0│0 1│1 0│1 1│
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

How can I refactor the part in parentheses to remove the duplication?

**clarification**:

The goal here isn't to produce the table, but rather to learn how to produce new verbs dynamically. In order to reduce the parenthesized expression, I would want to factor out the symbols `;` , `/` and `b.` , and then replace the numbers with `i.10`.

The `;` symbol is easy enough:

```
   ;/i.16
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┐
│0│1│2│3│4│5│6│7│8│9│10│11│12│13│14│15│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┘
```

But I'm having a hard time finding a way to produce a new verb from each element in the list.

I think maybe I'm looking for some kind of higher-order combinators that allow using `&` and `@` with something other than constants.

For example, `nn leftBondEach v` might make an array of verbs equivalent to `n0 & v; n1 & v; ... ; nn & v` :

```
   bverbs =: (i.16)(leftBondEach)b. NB. would mean (0 b.; 1 b.; ...; 15 b.)
   0 bverbs 0
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│0│0│0│0│0│0│0│0│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
   0 bverbs 1
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│0│0│0│0│1│1│1│1│0│0│0│0│1│1│1│1│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

I think I need something similar in order to append the `/` to each function.

Then again, this is J and there's probably a completely different way to approach these problems that I just haven't grokked yet. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
<"2@|:@( (i.16) b./~) 0 1

    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    |0 0|0 0|0 1|0 1|0 0|0 0|0 1|0 1|1 0|1 0|1 1|1 1|1 0|1 0|1 1|1 1|
    |0 0|0 1|0 0|0 1|1 0|1 1|1 0|1 1|0 0|0 1|0 0|0 1|1 0|1 1|1 0|1 1|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Just noticing that `$ (i. 16) b. /~ 0 1` is 2 2 16, and you'd want to have 16 boxes with size 2x2 ...

Comment: AHA! Thanks! I couldn't understand why `b.` didn't behave like "other verbs"... And now I see it's because it's not a verb but an adverb. :)

Looks like this general technique works with other adverbs too `((i.10)&+)5` → `5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14`.

Exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Boxing the individual truth-tables strikes me as an afterthought. Indeed, the phrasing in the J sentence in this answer communicates exactly that: boxing the tables is a thought that comes after their production. The transposition is worthwhile, though, as a list of tables (shape of 16 2 2) seems the naturally advantageous answer.

Comment: @jpcacobs, I think you're missing a `(` between `@` and `i.`.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the catch. Well, actually, there is one too much between `b.` and `/` :) Corrected.

Comment: I don't think the use of under (`&.`) adds anything here. It could be replaced by atop (`@`)

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward conversion, I can think of, is:

```
(3 :'y b./ ~ i.2') each i.16
```

**edit** on clarification

*1.* You can define something like `f =: 4 :';/x b. y'`, so:

```
(i.16) f 0
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│0│0│0│0│0│0│0│0│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
(i.16) f 1
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│0│0│0│0│1│1│1│1│0│0│0│0│1│1│1│1│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

*2.* You can "apply" `;/` to `(i.16) b.` with At (`@`):

```
f =: ;/@((i.16) b.)
f 0
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│0│0│0│0│0│0│0│0│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
f 1
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│0│0│0│0│1│1│1│1│0│0│0│0│1│1│1│1│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

*3.* if you want `leftBondEach` to work on any verb, then it's a conjuction:

```
leftBondEach =: 2 :';/m v y'   
h =: 2 leftBondEach +             NB. equiv. to h =: ;/@(2&+)
h 3 4 5
┌─┬─┬─┐
│5│6│7│
└─┴─┴─┘
h =: 0 leftBondEach ((i.16) b.)
h 0
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│0│0│0│0│0│0│0│0│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│1│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
h 1
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│0│0│0│0│1│1│1│1│0│0│0│0│1│1│1│1│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

*4. etc* you can reshape the result like [jpjacobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19398035/349708) did etc.

Comment: Hmm. That's definitely a huge improvement, but I only want the part in parentheses. The result should be an array of dyadic verbs. `b.` is a weird verb and I can't figure out how to correctly bind anything to it. E.g. `(3 : 'y & b.') each i.16` is syntax error, as is pretty much everything else I've tried. :(

Comment: Yes, `x b./~` seems a bit difficult to handle. Maybe you can define a helper adverb. I don't understand what you mean by "I only want the part in parentheses". What would be your ideal final structure? (You might want to add this to your question.)

Comment: Thanks. I added a section to (hopefully) clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @tangentstorm Still not sure :) but added some more things anyway. Hope it helps.